# iOS Auto Renewal Subscriptions - Alert confirmation callback

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

How can I check when the user tap the accept button in the last Alert showed by Apple after the user make a subscription purchase.

I have the following code

```
public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchased:
            complete(transaction: transaction)
        case .failed:
            fail(transaction: transaction)
        case .restored:
            restore(transaction: transaction)
        case .deferred:
            break
        case .purchasing:
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

But the `complete` method is called before user tap on the Alert.

How can I check the  Alert callback ?

[image]